# Searching for element in binary tree, function always returns 0

Tags: c, binary-tree

I wrote the following function in C that returns 1 if the element is indeed in the binary tree and 0 otherwise.

```
int isElementInBinaryTree(BinaryTreeNode *root, int search_item) {
if(root) {
    if(search_item == root -> data) return 1;
    isElementInBinaryTree(root -> left, search_item);
    isElementInBinaryTree(root -> right, search_item);
}

return 0;
}
```

First I enter the function to see if the root is there, if it is, i look at the data at that root and compare it to the search_item. If true, I simply return 1 and exit, other wise i continue the pre-order traversal. Why do I always get a return 0 regardless ? Even if the item is in the binary tree ?

Answer (score 4):

Change these lines

```
isElementInBinaryTree(root -> left, search_item);
isElementInBinaryTree(root -> right, search_item);
```

to return the result.

i.e.

```
return isElementInBinaryTree(root -> left, search_item) ||  isElementInBinaryTree(root -> right, search_item);
```

If the item is found in the LHS it returns true - otherwise it will try RHS. Note the use of `||` - short circuit operator

**EDIT**

Can get this into one return statement

```
int isElementInBinaryTree(BinaryTreeNode *root, int search_item)
{
   return root ? (search_item == root -> data || isElementInBinaryTree(root -> left, search_item) || isElementInBinaryTree(root -> right, search_item)) : 0;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Making an assumption that you are searching for a item that is used to order the tree with LHS being less than and the RHS being greater than.

The code should look like

```
int isElementInBinaryTree(BinaryTreeNode *root, int search_item)
{
    if(root) {
        // Assuming that most of the items in the tree are not the search item
        // best to check first if we need to search LHS or RHS - these
        // events are more likely than the item being found!
        if (search_item < root -> data) return isElementInBinaryTree(root -> left, search_item);
        if (search_item > root -> data) return isElementInBinaryTree(root -> right, search_item);
       return 1; // We have found it
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also recursively searching the left and then right completely negates the point of having the binary tree. Instead it should make a choice to recurse into the left OR the right depending if the current value is larger or smaller than the one you are looking for.

Comment: @GrahamS - The searching may be due to searching for an item in the node that is not used in the ordering for the construction of the binary tree

Comment: The OP is comparing the `node->data` to the `search_item` so I think it is safe to assume that the binary tree is sorted with respect to `node->data` and if it isn't then what's the point of it being a binary tree??

Comment: @GrahamS - That assumption should be checked with the poster

Answer (score 4):

You don't use the return value of the recursive calls to `isElementInBinaryTree`. You must propagate the result of the recursive calls to the topmost call. The way it is now it will return 1 only when the target item is at the root node.

So:

```
int isElementInBinaryTree(BinaryTreeNode *root, int search_item)
{
    if(root) {
        if (search_item == root -> data) return 1;
        if (isElementInBinaryTree(root -> left, search_item)) return 1;
        if (isElementInBinaryTree(root -> right, search_item)) return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note that the third condition check is redundant, simply return the result from the call.

Comment: However, there are pros and cons to this approach, which depends on the order o the elements in the tree. Your approach may traverse the left tree even if the element happens to be on the right sub-tree due to it's precedence in the call sequence, which runs Ok, but takes extra search.  Similarly, the approach suggested by@grahams below, would compare the search item with root node date twice, one before entering the sub-tree, one after entering the sub-tree, if that exists at all, but avoids searching the sub-tree if it isn't there. This sort of thing is avoided only  in edit-2 of @ed-heal.

Comment: @ravi: Long comment. My answer addresses the OP's core problem: the return value isn't used. It is not clear from the post that the tree is a binary search tree and that the search can be limited to only one subtree. Without that information, I have modelled my answer on the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

Not only do you need to return the values from the recursive calls, you should also only recurse into the parts of the tree that may contain your `search_item`.

So assuming the tree is sorted with lower=left then you function should look more like:

```
int isElementInBinaryTree(BinaryTreeNode *root, int search_item)
{
    if(root) {
        if (search_item == root -> data) return 1;
        else if (search_item < root -> data) return isElementInBinaryTree(root -> left, search_item);
        else if (search_item > root -> data) return isElementInBinaryTree(root -> right, search_item);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do not need `if (search_item > root -> data)`. Or the first `else` as well

Comment: Also the second `else` would be superfluous

Comment: They are mutually exclusive conditions, but structuring it like that makes the intention very clear.

Comment: How would those extra comparisons come about?

Comment: You're right, I redacted that just before you commented. :) The early returns avoid the extra comparisons. 
But I'd still structure it like that though if I was looking for that terse style (and my coding standards allowed the use of early returns) as it makes the intention very clear.

Comment: I would leave out the equality and return 1 at the end after the comparisons - see my answer for why

Comment: Yep, makes sense to have equality as the fall-through case. Well done for retrospectively editing your answer to include mine - is that how one gets to 33.7k rep? ;)

Comment: I could not think of a way of showing you the code that I think would be better than yours (wrt order of ifs etc). If you want and modify you code I will remove it

Comment: No worries. I'm just teasing you. I'm not really bothered.

Comment: I like being teased - But that discussion belongs to a totally different forum :-)